# How to get complete response for Groovy RestClient failed response

Tags: groovy, rest-client

Currently, I'm getting HttpResponseException, which has only statusCode.
How can I get complete body of response?

Here is code I'm using

```
restClient = new RESTClient("http://${Server}")
try {
    HttpResponseDecorator resp = restClient.post(path,body,requestContentType)     
        as HttpResponseDecorator
    return JSONObject.fromObject(resp.getData()).get("topKey","");
    }
catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            error(e.toString())
    }
```

And it only output this:

```
[oaf.error] groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add custom failed response handler:

```
        restClient = new RESTClient("http://${Server}")
        restClient.handler.failure = { resp, data ->
            resp.setData(data)
            String headers = ""
            resp.headers.each {
                headers = headers+"${it.name} : ${it.value}\n"
            }
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp.getStatus(),"HTTP call failed. Status code: ${resp.getStatus()}\n${headers}\n"+
                                            "Response: "+(resp as HttpResponseDecorator).getData())
        }
```

Comment: I find it strange that `data` is not already included in `resp`, given that `resp.setData()` is a non-public method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can extract the full response from the exception thrown. For example if your caught exception is `e` and response body JSON should contain a field called `myCustomErrorCode`, you can check its value by looking at `e.response.data.myCustomErrorCode` in addition to `e.statusCode`.